# Redefinition of formal parameters c++, trying to pass constructors

Tags: c++

Hi I am passing a constructor(with parameters) from one class into another class's constructor(with parameters). I am receiving a redefinition of formal parameters error, I understand what this error entails. My classes are inherited correctly I know this for a fact.

Here is the constructor(with one parameter) from the first class.

```
template <typename DataType>
List<DataType>:: List ( int maxNumber )
: maxSize(maxNumber),
size(0),
cursor(-1)
{
  dataItems = new DataType[maxSize];
}
```

Here is the constructor from the other class:

```
template < typename DataType, typename KeyType >
OrderedList<DataType, KeyType>::OrderedList(int maxNumber)
{
List<DataType>(maxNumber);//This is where it says I have a redefinition (ERROR HERE)
}
```

I know I can fix it like this:

```
template < typename DataType, typename KeyType >
OrderedList<DataType, KeyType>::OrderedList(int maxNumber)  : List<DataType>(maxNumber)
{
}
```

What I want to know is how can I convert that line directly above into a line similar to the middle code block? Also why am I receiving this error?

Please help.

Comment: First, welcome to StackOverflow, and please post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when asking a question. `List(maxNumber);` should be `List<DataType>(maxNumber);`, and even then that's almost definitely not what you want. The last snippet, where you use the constructor's mem-initializer list is the right way to initialize a non-default constructible base class or data member.

Comment: Please edit your question, and replace it completely with the real problem you're trying to solve. Your problem is certainly an XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), where you think that initializing a superclass in the body of the subclass's constructor is the answer, and the problem is how to do it. But it's not. Please explain the real problem you're trying to solve by using this superclass construction approach, instead.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have finished this XY problem by adding two questions at the end and removing the first question I had at the beginning.

Comment: @Praetorian I made a change to my code, but I still states there is a redefinition of the integer maxNumber? Also I cannot shorten the code of these class because they are dependent on 4 headers, 5 implementations, and 5 main files. The code will have many other errors if I attempt to shorten it using MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that to construct a List object, you need to pass in a parameter to it's constructor. That needs to happen before any derived classes are constructed. Therefore:

```
template < typename DataType, typename KeyType >
OrderedList<DataType, KeyType>::OrderedList(int maxNumber)
{
List<DataType>(maxNumber);//This is where it says I have a redefinition (ERROR HERE)
}
```

Is nonsense code. What is it trying to say? That you want to choose the point during which the base class constructor is called? Unfortunately C++ doesn't work that way. Base class constructor is called first, then derived constructors. Destructors work the opposite.

Also, to explain why you are getting this error, let's rewrite your code in different but equivalent to the compiler ways:

```
template < typename DataType, typename KeyType >
OrderedList<DataType, KeyType>::OrderedList(int maxNumber)
{
List<DataType>(maxNumber);//This is where it says I have a redefinition (ERROR HERE)

List<DataType> (maxNumber);
List<DataType> maxNumber;
AnyOtherType maxNumber; // You see, you are declaring a local variable with the same name as your parameter?
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I understand now :)!!@user3690202 Is the only way then to use a member initialization list?

Comment: @Atlas In this case, yes. :-)